# How to run a flask app into VS Code by button instead of going to the startup file?

Tags: python, debugging, flask, visual-studio-code, startup

I have a `flask` program into `VS Code`. After config project, I expect that click `debugging button` will run the app with debug mode. So it happens, but **only** first time.

When I click a `stop button` and again `debugging` - comes the error. I don't see that when click `debugging button` instead the window with text after delay.

[image]

If I run last terminal command, will the error `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]`.

```
"d:\Python Projects\HelloFlask\venv\Scripts\python.exe" c:\Users\Owl\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py
--default --client --host localhost --port 56369 -m flask run --no-debugger --no-reload
```

If I run only, the app was running

```
flask run --no-debugger --no-reload
```

Why after success the first run with `debugging button`, every next with error ones of describe above? What do I need to do to run the project **by button**? Now have to either re-enter the VS Code or go to the startup file and run it. It's awkward.

The app has the next config and structure

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "runserver.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean by 'debugging button' and 'debugging'? And you can't re-run the command in the terminal as-is because the port may have changed.

Comment: @BrettCannon added a screenshot of button.  'debugging button' and 'debugging' is the same. If I can't re-run, how do debug twice and more time?

Comment: that should be working. Please make sure you are using the latest version of the extension. If you are then please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.